# angular sends an octet-stream to my webservice instead of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, web-services, angularjs

I have a spring web service which works fine but it will not add an 'factuur'. If i use a restclient and do a post to add an 'factuur' to my database it will succed but when i do it in my client app which is in angularjs it return a:

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

my controller in the spring webservice:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void add(@RequestBody FacturatieView factuur){
        facturatieService.addFacturatie(factuur);
    }
```

and in my angular app i have the following:

```
factory('factuurFactory', function($resource) {

            return $resource('http://localhost:8084/publictms/factuur/:id?CALLBACK=JSONP_CALLBACK', {}, {
                show: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}},
                delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
            });

        }).
        // In deze factory kan men alle voertuigen ophalen, wijzigen of een nieuwe toevoegen
        factory('facturenFactory', function($resource) {

            return $resource('http://localhost:8084/publictms/factuur/?CALLBACK=JSONP_CALLBACK', {}, {
                all: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                create: {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}},
                update: {method: 'PUT', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
            });

        }).
        // CONTROLLER
        // Controller om de facturen te tonen en om een factuur te verwijderen
        controller('factuurCtrl', function($scope, $location, factuurFactory, facturenFactory) {

            // Haal de lijst van factuur op
            $scope.getList = function() {
                facturenFactory.all(function(data) {
                    $scope.facturen = data;
                });
            };

            // Navigeer naar een nieuw factuur aanmaken
            $scope.add = function() {
                $location.path('admin/facturen/nieuw');
            };

            // Navigeer naar de details van een factuur
            $scope.update = function(factuurId) {
                $location.path('admin/factuur/' + factuurId);
            };

            // Verwijder een factuur
            $scope.delete = function(factuurId) {
                factuurFactory.delete({id: factuurId}, function() {
                    $scope.getList();
                });
            };

            $scope.getList();

        }).
        // Controller om de details van een factuur te tonen en te wijzigen
        controller('factuurDetailCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, factuurFactory, facturenFactory) {
            $scope.state = true;
            $scope.factuur = factuurFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
            $scope.edit = function() {
                $scope.state = false;
            };
            $scope.save = function() {
                facturenFactory.update($scope.factuur);
                $scope.state = true;
            };
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $scope.state = true;
            };
        }).
```

note if i set an mediatype in my controller i will not accept this octet-stream. Anyone knows why angular is sending a octet-stream instead of json? Also the update method works fine.

Comment: What happens if you leave off the header?

Comment: dunno, but the problem was not the code but in my html, wrong data-binding. but thanks anyway